# How do I add a project as a dependency to my common.gradle?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a project structure that looks like the following:

```
-Root Project 1
 settings.gradle
 build.gradle
 common.gradle <-Where my dependencies are declared
   -SubProject A
    .build.gradle
   -SubProject B
    .build.gradle
   -SubProject C
    .build.gradle

-Root Project 2
 settings.gradle
 build.gradle
 common.gradle
   -SubProject D
    .build.gradle
```

What I'd like to do is add SubProject D as a dependency to RootProject 1, so that SubProjects A, B, and C can access it's classes. What do I change in the Root Project 1 build scripts to achieve this?

Currently the common .gradle declares dependencies like so

```
dependencies {
     compile(group: 'com.software.core', name: 'ApplicationElements', version: '7.1.1-60')
}
```

However, that's referencing a jar from artifactory, in this case I would like to reference a local project instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `compile` for your dependencies. That means you are using an outdated version of the Android gradle plugin. Newer version of the gradle plugin have introduced some concepts, to achieve exactly what you want.

If you are able to update to the latest Android gradle plugin (which I recommend to get other benefits such as much faster builds) you should use `api`:

```
api "com.software.core:ApplicationElements:7.1.1-60" // transitively add dependencies
```

vs

```
implementation "com.software.core:ApplicationElements:7.1.1-60" // do not leak module dependencies upwards
```

If you are NOT able to update the gradle plugin version, I recommend you [read this page](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies), which describes dependencies, both old and new styles.